# Does a buffer_unordered wait for a tokio::spawn?

Tags: multithreading, rust, rust-tokio

I have some code with `buffer_unordered` waiting for `tokio::spawn`. But I feel like this is not the proper method because the former handles a `future` while the latter is more about concurrency more than asynchronization (although these intersect at some point).

Anyway, having like `some_vector.iter().map(tokio::spawn(async move {...}).buffer_unordered(...)...` is sometimes waiting for the threads to finish and sometimes not.

Can you please explain in more detail why? And how to handle the `join` outside the `.map()`?

**Update**:
I am not sure if this code sample is good reproduction, but just to give you a sample of the big code.

```
use anyhow::anyhow;
use futures::{stream, StreamExt, TryFutureExt, TryStreamExt};
    
fn main() {
    let some_vector = vec!['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];

    func(some_vector);
}

async fn func(some_vector: Vec<char>) -> Result<Vec<char>, anyhow::Error> {
    let vec_iter = stream::iter(some_vector);
    let new_vec: Vec<_> = vec_iter
        .map(|some_char| {
            tokio::spawn(async move {
                //a sample resource consuming loop
                for mut n in 0..10000001 {
                    n += 1;
                    if n == 10000000 {
                        println!("finished {}'s thread", some_char);
                    }
                }
                some_char
            })
        })
        .buffer_unordered(5)
        .try_collect()
        .await
        .map_err(|_| anyhow!("Critical Error"))?;
    Ok(new_vec)
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example?

Comment: Two remarks: 1) This code doesn't do anything, since you don't execute the future returned from `func`. Here's an example how to make it work, tweak it as you need - https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c9241c33acbff9d43207153c9b6cfd70. 2) `tokio::spawn` is not about threads - these five tasks in real code can very well end up at the same thread, if runtime is concurrently busy with something else.

Comment: Run the playground above a couple of times - every time it was printing all five "finished" messages, so the problem seems to be somewhere else, not in this part.

Comment: Thanks @Cerberus, it seems that your playground saves my day. The problem seems to be in calling the function, and seems tokio::runtime is how idiomatically solve it. Please feel free to write an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The key thing here it's that they will arrive to the finish line *concurrently*, so the executors does not care about anything, just `buffer_unordered(...)` will act as a cop, stopping there the traffic until they are all there, mapped well to a result, or as an error. Then, they will run sync to the `try_collect()`.

As other people pointed out, the tokio part that you're using is all about *concurrent* code. So, to answer your question, it always "waits" until the buffer advices that every spawned task has ended. That's is real behaviour under the hood.

But wait, from the docs for tokio::join!:

`By running all async expressions on the current task, the expressions are able to run concurrently but not in parallel. This means all expressions are run on the same thread and if one branch blocks the thread, all other expressions will be unable to continue. If parallelism is required, spawn each async expression using tokio::spawn and pass the join handle to join!.`

Hope this solve your questions.